# Using SWIG to build Python Module using 3rd-Party Drivers

Tags: python, oop, visual-c++, ctypes, swig

I'm using a 3rd-Party Vendor who is providing a Windows Driver (DLL) and C Header Files. What I'm trying to do is use SWIG to recompile the header file into a Python Module.

Here are the my files: 
- BTICard.i 
- BTICard.h 
- BTICARD64.dll 
- BTICARD64.lib

## SWIG interface source

```
%module BTICard
%include <windows.i>
%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "BTICard.H"
#define BTICardAPI
%}
```

In Cygwin, I used the following commands:

```
swig -python -py3 BTICard.i
```

Which then generated the following files: 
- BTICard.py 
- BTICard_wrap.c

In Cygwin, compile for Python Module

```
gcc -c -fpic BTICARD.H BTICard_wrap.c -I/usr/include/python3.8
```

Which now allows BTICard to be imported in Python

```
import BTICard
import ctypes
BTICarddll = ctypes.WinDLL('BTICARD64')
pRec1553 = SEQRECORD1553() # Doesn't initialize
```

The BTICard.H contains the following:  
typedef struct - Used to initialize various field structures 
enum - Constant Declarations

According to the SWIG documentation, the typedef structs are supposed to be converted into Python classes. When I tried initializing the class, I got a NameError. I suspect the issue is with my interface file not recognizing these types so it failed to convert them.

Upon further investigation, I tried using the distutils approach and created the setup.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.8
"""
setup.py file for SWIG
"""
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

example_module = Extension('_BTICard',
    sources=['BTICard_wrap.c', 'BTICard.h'],)

setup (name = 'BTICard',
    version = '0.1',
    author = "TESTER",
    description = """BTICard API""",
    ext_modules = [example_module],
    py_modules = ["BTICard"],
    )
```

To build the package:

```
$ python3.8 setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
building '_BTICard' extension
error: unknown file type '.h' (from 'BTICard.h')
```

What's the issue here?

Is there a way I can access the Python source file after creating the object from gcc?

All I am trying to do is to validate a separate Python Wrapper that seems to have issues (it's a completely separate topic). Is there another way to create this Python Module?

Answer (score 1):

The `.i` file isn't including the interface to export.  It should look like:

```
%module BTICard

%{
#include "BTICard.H"    // this just makes the interface available to the wrapper.
%}

%include <windows.i>
%include "BTICard.h"    // This wraps the interface defined in the header.
```

`setup.py` knows about SWIG interfaces, so include the `.i` file directly as a source.  Headers are included by the sources and aren't listed *as* sources.  You may need other options but this should get you on the right track.  You'll likely need the DLLs export library (`BTICard.lib`) and need to link to that as well:

```
example_module = Extension('_BTICard',
    sources=['BTICard.i'],
    libraries=['BTICard.lib'])
```